# Clear trailing spaces after pasted number in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, trailing-whitespace

How do we strip out spaces at the end of the 10digit number when user copies it from place (like email or word docs etc) and pastes it in the search bar?

But this function is only working when we hit enter.
I want blank spaces to be removed as soon as we paste number.

```
public onSearchPolicy( event: any){
 let search policy number= event.target?.value?.trim();
if ( searchPolicyNumber){
let searchPolicyObject = {
policy : searchPolicyNumber,}};
```

Comment: You can handle the `input` event of an input element. It fires when the value of the input element changes (thus it also fires when pasting something into the input element).

Comment: you can listen to the change and apply trim every change but its over killing and when you do want space user could not enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question, just **keep it simple** and:

1. **Get the element** your pasting it in

`document.getElementById` or however your binding it in Angular (`@ViewChild`, etc).

2. Then **remove the spaces** - `yourElementText.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

You could apply your function when the search input change.

.html

```
<input (ngModelChange)="onSearchChange()" />
```

.ts

```
onSearchChange() {
    // Your code
}
```